# Optimizing a complex CUDA kernel to improve memory and compute efficiency

Tags: performance, memory, cuda, nvidia, overhead

I recently converted an [OpenCL kernel](https://github.com/fangq/mmc/blob/master/src/mmc_core.cl) to CUDA, and ran `nvvp`, and found out the below [two lines of code](https://github.com/fangq/mmc/blob/master/src/mmc_core.cl#L470-L471) placed a heavy toll to the speed of my code:

```
#define FL4(f) make_float4(f,f,f,f)
float4 S = FL4(r->vec.x)*normal[eid]+FL4(r->vec.y)*normal[eid+1]+FL4(r->vec.z)*normal[eid+2];
float4 T = normal[eid+3] - (FL4(r->p0.x)*normal[eid]+FL4(r->p0.y)*normal[eid+1]+FL4(r->p0.z)*normal[eid+2]);
```

where each `normal[i]` is a `float4` (read-only) in the global memory, and as you can see, I need to read 3x `normal`s to compute `S` and 4x `normal`s (3 of them overlap with the prior line) to compute `T`. So, a total of 64 bytes are needed for these two lines, making them responsible for nearly 90% of the memory latency of my code.

**Update [04/18/2020]**

To reproduce this, one can follow the below simple commands (optimizing this code is only meaningful given the existing functionality and complexity of the software, so I would like to investigate this without decimating the kernel)

```
git clone https://github.com/fangq/mmc_trinity.git
cd mmc_trinity/src
git checkout trinity
make clean
make cuda
cd ../examples/validation
./run_tess.sh -n 1e6 -D T -c cuda -G 1
```

To compile the above code, you need to have cuda(nvcc) pre-installed on your system. The makefile should work on Linux, Mac and cygwin64/mys2 on windows. Use `-G ??` to select which GPU to use, use `-c cuda -L` to list all cuda devices. Increase 1e6 to 1e7 or 1e8 if you have a capable GPU.

Currently, the speed (`-n 1e8`) from the above benchmark using the pre-optimized kernel is

```
22507.31 photon/ms on Titan V
16051.36 photon/ms on RTX 2080
 8112.93 photon/ms on GTX 1080Ti
 5050.76 photon/ms on GTX 980Ti
```

The full kernel file (opencl/cuda compatible) can be found at
https://github.com/fangq/mmc_trinity/blob/trinity/src/mmc_core.cl

the two hotspots I mentioned are located at
https://github.com/fangq/mmc_trinity/blob/trinity/src/mmc_core.cl#L526-L527

The cuda-related host code can be found at
https://github.com/fangq/mmc_trinity/blob/trinity/src/mmc_cu_host.cu

**I would like to significantly improve the execution speed, especially reduce the memory overhead of the hotspots.**

I previously thought that each global memory read in CUDA comes with a 128-byte cache line - so, reading 1x float vs 4x `float4` cost the same. However, the memory latency I observed from these two lines are dramatically higher than what I expect for reading a single float.

Below is the output from `nvvp`. I would like to hear what you think about on strategies to cut the memory reading cost of these two lines. One thing I want to mention that this code implements the Monte Carlo algorithm. there is very little coalescence between threads due to the random nature of the execution.

[image]

Comment: The first stage of any serious optimization exercise is to compile and then dissassemble to see what the compiler did to your code, and then statically analyze the PTX or SASS to understand the dataflows. I don't know how to optimize two totally out of context LOC. I doubt anyone else who is serious does either.

Comment: one of my doubts was about the 128 byte cache line - I don't fully understand why my code is not benefit from such cache.

Comment: among other things I would like to hear (which I am trying right now) is whether moving `normal[]` to texture memory will help reduce such overhead.

Comment: full source code and benchmark commands, results are now provided in the question, also added a bounty, appreciate suggestions that can speed up this code.

Comment: Do you think a 1900 LOC repro case for an optimization problem claimed to be related to two lines of code might be a little bit excessive?

Comment: I am sure it is not, but I am sure optimizing those two lines will help a lot, at least based on the profiler output. If you think there are other major hot spots that the profiler missed, please share (and show evidence).

Comment: Can you reduce your optimization problem to a snippet that shows a comparable behavior to the 2 lines you believe to be the bottleneck of your program? Minimal in [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) means "…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem". Perhaps a bounty may not be enough of a motivation for people to go over somebody else's project on this scale.

Comment: Just to avoid further confusion, I changed this question's title. My goal here is to optimize a complex Monte Carlo simulation kernel - such optimization is only meaningful when keeping the entire algorithm structure (i.e. all existing features). To mention about the profiling results and the memory latency of a hotspot is just my effort of trying to make this discuss more focused, but I am open to all effective improvements that are outside these two lines.

Comment: Low memory performance with memory reading overlaps? This is perfect for tiling. Have you tried it?

Comment: the main challenge here is that this code implements an Monte Carlo algorithm, which by nature simulates random photons and requires randomized access to memory along such paths. While a photon may have higher chance to move around the source (if point src), but it will also navigate throughout the volume, thus, locality is something already does not exist in this type of algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an update:**

After moving the frequently accessed `normal` data (by sorting distances of all tetrahedra w.r.t. to the source position) to the constant memory, the memory latency dropped from 27% to 4%, and is no longer a bottleneck.

here is the commit that had fixed the memory latency:

https://github.com/fangq/mmc_trinity/commit/9ed59da8ec6b88375b9bdf1f7798f906ef8a5c65

although memory latency is largely removed, instruction dependency now took over, and grow from 37% to 51% in the PC sampling profiling results. see the pie-chart at the bottom. I am not surprised for this, but was a little bit surprised to see the simulation speed went down a little bit on Titan V, opposite to 1080Ti and 980Ti.

```
before     after
22507.31  19204.92  photon/ms on Titan V    (slower)
 8112.93   9983.03  photon/ms on GTX 1080Ti (faster)
 5050.76   5518.46  photon/ms on GTX 980Ti  (faster)
```

It appears that the high register count (104) remains the biggest bottleneck (although very little we can do without completely changing the algorithm).

I remain open to suggestions in effectively optimizing this code, and will be available for further clarifications and discussions in this thread. thanks in advance.

[image]